# Automotive reverse current and transient protection

Tags: automotive, protection, transient, reverse-polarity

Adding reverse polarity and reverse current protection to an automotive circuit seems a bit challenging, especially when driving loads in the 10 A range (e.g. seat heater). Diodes on the power line would present too much loss and heat in this case.

After having spent quite a lot of time studying solutions for this task I came up with this circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fRxGEB.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

As of my understanding, this circuit would function as follows:

- D1 & D2 are TVS diodes to suppress load dumps in both directions with min. breakdown at 25.7 V and max. breakdown at 48.3 V (considering standard pulses)
- M1 is supplying power to the downstream circuits, that is supposed to serve as reverse battery protection as well. R1 & D3 should keep Vgs at a safe level of 10V. As soon as the internal diode of M1 starts to conduct, R1 & D3 can turn M1 fully on, eliminating further internal diode loss. R2 should stabilize Vgs.
- D4 is supposed to handle negative transients. As per my understanding, it takes some time for M1 to turn off in case of a negative transient, during which a large amount of current is allowed to pass backwards along M1 and downstream circuits. The idea is to let D4 direct away most of the current during this short period, leaving only a safe portion to downstream circuits to handle.

Constrained VCC should be thus between:

- max. 48.3 V (D2 TVS diode breakdown voltage)
- min. approx. -0.4 V (D4 Schottky diode forward voltage drop)

Are my assumptions correct, is this circuit working this way? Did I miss something?

I know there are specifically designed parts for this task, but unfortunately they're not available in my area.

Comment: I dot't see what D1 buys you : surely it only increases the stress on D4?

Comment: If D1 wasn't there, D2 alone would create a short in a reverse battery situation

Comment: Ah. I was assuming a reasonable value of fuse upstream. in which case the short provides protection by disconnecting the unit via the fuse.

Comment: There is an upstream fuse of course, but my goal is to make it as robust as possible, this means surviving common fault cases unnoticed. I'd rather only leave "the unexpected" to the fuse to handle.